# What is the significance of increasing (and decreasing) the number of ionic releaxation steps in a plane wave DFT calcuation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

The number of ionic relaxation steps is one of the adjustable parameters while setting up a DFT calculation using a commercial code such as VASP. I was wondering what's the significance of this value?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! Regarding your question, it could be greatly improved by giving a more detailed description of your specific problem. Giving an example would go a long way toward this end.  It also reads like a homework-type question, and I suggest reading [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) discussion regarding homework-type questions.  Good luck!